# what statistical analyzes can I perform between a transcriptome and candidate sequences obtained from this same transcriptome?

Tags: cluster-analysis, bioinformatics, statistics-bootstrap, statistical-test, web-statistics

I have an assembled **transcriptome**.
I performed analyses on this transcriptome to extract **candidate sequences** involved in the production of a substance.
Then, I annotated both sets of data using the** Eggnog Mapper tool**.
This is an example of my result table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo8S4.png)
Being new to bioinformatic, I am currently stuck on which **statistical analysis** to perform to determine the functions most involved in the production of the substance, and what other analyses can I perform with these two sets of data? The eggnog annotation results didn't give the gene ID.

I have tried the **overrepresentation test** a **functional enrichment analysis** for COGs (Clusters of Orthologous Groups); COGs annotation and redondance in a table and to compare between the two set of data; using the R code https://yulab-smu.top/biomedical-knowledge-mining-book/enrichment-overview.html#gsea-algorithm , with clusterProfiler but it seems that it may not work beacause I don't have gene IDs in my annotation results eggNOG doesn't give it. With which tools or code can I perform this test, please?

Comment: The [bioinformatics] tag is for *programming-related* questions related to Bioinformatics. Other questions do not belong here, but might be on-topic at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/.